# how to crack the DES encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cracking

How to break the DES encryption algorithm....using which programming language, it is most efficient.

Comment: If you have to ask, doing this isn't for you.

Comment: You expect to get an answer to a two sentence question about something even security experts [haven't had much success with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Security_and_cryptanalysis) for years and that whole research papers have been written about?!

Comment: @deceze: You should see this http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925205

And there are tools available to crack the DES...such as John The Ripper and even you can download the source code for the same....

Comment: To quote your link: `...designed and built a $200,000 machine that cracks DES in a week.` All feasible DES attacks are based on **brute force**. That doesn't really mean that DES is *cracked*, it means it's possible to guess the encrypted text given enough money and time, a property *all* encryption algorithms have in common. JTR's `primary purpose is to detect weak Unix passwords`, which means the same thing. DES may be one of the more feasibly brute-forcable algorithms, it still doesn't mean the same thing as *cracked*.

Comment: @deceze: Do u mean to say that JTR is meant for cracking DES encrypted password??

Comment: @deceze: Here is a demonstration on cracking the DES encrypted password using JTR...http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=455

Comment: Huh? I'm saying JTR is also only brute-forcing an encrypted value, with a focus on known weak passwords, it doesn't *crack* DES. Choose a strong enough password and JTR will have a hard time.

Comment: JTR can be run against various encrypted password formats including several crypt password hash types most commonly found on various Unix flavors (based on DES, MD5, or Blowfish), Kerberos AFS, and Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 LM hash.

Comment: I will stop here and wait until you understand what *brute-force* means.

Comment: brute-force means checking the password, with all possible combination of a-z,A-Z,0-9 and special characters with variable password length.

Comment: Exactly. Which means you're not *cracking the algorithm*, you're only guessing the encrypted value. *Cracking the algorithm* would mean there's an inherent weakness in the algorithm that lets you reverse engineer the original value from the cypher text without needing to try every possible combination. That's quite an important difference.

Comment: No doubt, it will take a lot of computations and time to crack the password. But, it will crack the password...

Comment: But, now if you have strong processor to perform these computations in small amount of time, then you easily minimize time required to crack a strong password. Ultimately, the strength of password is immaterial.

Comment: Ultimately, the strength of the password is **everything**. If your password is `a`, it'll probably be the very first thing you try in your brute-force cycle. If the password is `ikwh9&*)Y9h^&TH897G(*h987y0y89&Jy89&to87jt8g56342&^908um908^y78%34*790(_<K)9*)` (let's say 100 characters in an alphabet of ~82 characters), it may take somewhere around 2.406497×10^191 cycles before you hit it. Let's assume you can make 1 billion cycles per second, it'd still take you up to 7.630950×10^174 years to hit it...

Comment: As was mentioned in your link, a $200.000 specialized machine took a week. And it didn't say in the blurb how long the brute-forced value was. Normal commercially available processors have a fraction of that power. I'll say it again: It comes down to your available **time and money**. That's the entire premise of cryptography, to make it **infeasible** to decrypt something, not **impossible**.

Comment: PS: Realistically DES is a bit easier to brute-force than that because of its small key space, but it still comes down to the strength of the password and the power of the machine you can run your brute-force on. That means, as I said, DES is feasibly brute-forceable, it's not *cracked*. `When DES was approved as a federal standard in 1976, a machine fast enough to test [all] keys in a reasonable time would have cost an unreasonable amount of money to build.` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker AES & co will face the same problem eventually.

Comment: Somehow I get the idea that the OP's idea of cryptography is based on Hollywood movies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)